# How to create a second form_login to authenticate users

Tags: symfony, security, firewall

i would like to create a second form_login to authenticate my users but with the same pattern.
here is a part of my security.yml

```
frontend:
    context: frontend
    pattern: ^/
    form_login:
        provider: fos_clientbundle
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        login_path : client_login
        check_path : client_check
        failure_path : null
        default_target_path : client_userprofile   
    form_login:
        provider: fos_clientbundle
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        login_path : ecommerce_front_checkout
        check_path : ecommerce_check
        failure_path : null
        default_target_path : ecommerce_front_checkout                     
    logout:       
      path : client_logout
      target : client_login
    anonymous:    true
```

but it don't work!!
I searched on the web but I have not found solutions.

it would require that users can connect through the main login page and also that it may be on another page like an e-commerce page!!

I hope you can help me.
thank you very much

Comment: If it is the same patter why not use the same form ? I think you may try to be more specific. Also reading documentation will help you. In my opionin this is something you are looking for: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

Comment: yes it is the same pattern.indeed i have a page which there is a form login only to connect.this page is accessible from the menu.i have an other page which there is a process to place an order.in second step of the process, there is a block whith form login to connect too.

Comment: Ok, then you need to read this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html

Comment: ok thanks.i look at this article!!

Comment: I just watched but this solution does not fit my case or I did not understand the interest of this method!!this method explain how to authenticate user with an api keys!!

Answer (score 0):

You could create two different controllers(or Actions) that both extends the BaseSecurityController and just override the renderLogin action(and any other if you need to override some things).

Define both controllers in the routing

routing.yml:

```
login:
    path: /{_locale}/login
    defaults: { _controller: ApplicationSonataUserBundle:SecurityFOSUser1:login }

loginForm:
    path: /{_locale}/login_frm
    defaults: { _controller: ApplicationSonataUserBundle:AnotherSecurityFOSUser1:login }
```

And then just display the form in a twig:

```
{% render url('loginForm') %}
```

Comment: the problem is if the authentication succeeded, the redirection is not the same.in my security.yml, the defaut_target_path is different

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution.it s'very easy!!
in my second form, i must to have add in the default_target_path and failure_path in my form such as :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="ecommerce_front_checkout" />
<input type="hidden" name="_failure_path" value="ecommerce_front_checkout" />
```

thank you very much for your help!!